# How can I set the AsynchMode of an ASP.NET page programatically?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page base class that has no .aspx file and so I therefore cannot set the page directive Asynch="true" - but I want pages that inherit from this base class to operate asynchronously - is there any way to set AsynchMode programatically in my base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting Asynch="true" basically tells ASP.NET that the page should inherit the IHttpAsyncHandler interface so it could be possible to just inherit this interface in your class directly however I have had not experience of doing this so cannot guarantee that this is a solution to your problem.

A quick google turfed up this article:

[Asynchronous pages in .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx)